# AAS Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided

Tags: azure

Currently, we are using **Service account** to refresh the Azure Analysis Service Tabular model using the Azure Automation account and now planning to move to **Service principal**

Below are the steps I followed to do the required setup:

1. Create a **Run as accounts** from the Automation Account screen
   [image]
2. The above step created a Service Principal in Azure Active Directory and using this I created a Client Secret. After this, I picked up the below values from the Service Principal:

Application (client) ID
Object ID
Directory (tenant) ID
Client Secret ID

[image]

3. Then, I have created a Credential in the Automation Account page using the <Application (client) ID> and <in the Azure Automation account

Username: <Application (client) ID>
Password:

[image]

4. Edited the Automation account Runbook to fetch the Service Principal credentials and then refresh the Azure Analysis Service. Below is the script:

   #Tls 1.2
   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

   #Base Values

   $databaseName = "Reporting-Tabular"

   $server = "asazure://.asazure.windows.net/AASServer"

   #Get Creds

   $Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'service-principal'

   Write-Output "Credential Obtained, invoking refresh"

   Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName $databaseName -RefreshType "Full" -Server $server -    ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential

   Write-Output "Done!"*
5. Added the **app:<Application (client) ID>@<Directory (tenant) ID>** to the Azure Analysis Services admin list using SSMS

I am getting the below error when I test the run book using the Test pane in the Automation account:

**Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided.**

[image]

Please help how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in the Automation Credential password try pasting app registration's secret **value** instead of secret id.